# Exception Thrown by Manatee.Trello.RestSharp.RestSharpResponse

Tags: manatee.trello

I just came across an exception while trying something with Manatee.Trello.  I was trying to create a Func like this:

```
var criteria = new List<string>
{
    "(put a board ID here)"
};

var query = new Func<IEnumerable<Manatee.Trello.Member>, IEnumerable<Manatee.Trello.Board>>(
    members =>
    {
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            var selectedBoards = member.Boards.Where(b => criteria.Contains(b.Id, StringComparer.Ordinal));

            boards.AddRange(selectedBoards); // Exception thrown here
        }

        return boards;
    });
```

But the line marked above throws this exception:

`System.TypeLoadException
{"Method 'get_StatusCode' in type 'Manatee.Trello.RestSharp.RestSharpResponse' from assembly 'Manatee.Trello.RestSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=783b036be1eaf5a7' does not have an implementation.":"Manatee.Trello.RestSharp.RestSharpResponse"}`

I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing wrong with my code, or some kind of setup error I made in setting up my project with Manatee.Trello, perhaps the NuGet packages are jacked up...

Any tips on where to start looking would be much appreciated.

Comment: This might be a RestSharp provider issue.  Switching to WebApi to see if that fixes it...

Comment: @bubbleking - It sure did.

Comment: Did you just tag yourself in a comment reply to yourself?

Comment: @gregsdennis - I sure did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation was remedied by changing from the RestSharp provider included in `Manatee.Trello` to the provider in `Manatee.Trello.WebApi`.  As I discovered in the [library's documentation](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/wiki/Supplying-your-own-ReST-client):

> Manatee.Trello.RestSharp is backed by (you guessed it) RestSharp.
>   There have been some issues with the .Net 4.5+ versions, so it's
>   suggested you don't use this one unless you are using .Net 4.0 or
>   earlier.

Indeed, I am using .Net 4.5.2.

Comment: You are correct. This is a problem inside RestSharp, although they deny it. I maintain an [open issue](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/issues/32) to track it. (It has been a while since I last tested this against any new versions, though.) This is the correct answer. Use the WebApi library.